# How to get continuous mousemove event when using android mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

using this code:

```
<h2 id="status">
0, 0
</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('html').mousemove(function(e){
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
</script>
```

In Windows browser like firefox, It's ok to see the mouse postion when I move mouse, but when I run this page in android(2.1) browser, I can not get the continuous event when I touch the screen, It just trigger the event when I tap the screen, why? and how to get the continuous mousemove event when I touch the screen?

Comment: may be 'cause it tries to drag the screen instead of getting your position?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `touchmove` event instead (works on my Android browser on Froyo), although there are some problems with it -- the browser only updates the div when the touch has been released, however the event is still fired for every touch movement. This can be demonstrated by changing the code to this:

> ```
> var x = 0;
> $('html').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
>     $('#status').html(x++); // Only updates on touch release
> });
> ```

This is due to a [bug in the Android browser](http://uihacker.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-touchmove-event-bug.html) -- you need to call `event.preventDefault()` to make this work as expected:

> ```
> var x = 0;
> $('html').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
>     e.preventDefault();
>     $('#status').html(x++); // Only updates on touch release
> });
> ```

Official bug details: [available here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5491)

To detect the current X and Y position you should use the `event.touches` object:

```
$(window).bind('touchmove', function(jQueryEvent) {
   jQueryEvent.preventDefault();
   var event = window.event;
   $('#status').html('x='+event.touches[0].pageX + '  y= ' + event.touches[0].pageY);
});
```

jQuery creates it's own "version" of the event object which doesn't have the native browsers properties such as `.touches` -- so you need use `window.event` instead

Comment: I tried this, but can not get X and Y postion using windows.event, seems using jQueryEvent.pageX and pageY is ok. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I just want to mention that the bug doesn't only happens on the Android browser, but Chrome (PC) as well. One thing I don't really like is that it also stopped other `touchmove` events which is very bad.

Answer (score 6):

After reading the accepted answer, perhaps the best way to deal with on-going events for both touch and mouse is something like this?

```
<div id="status">x, y</div>
<script>
    $('html').on("mousemove touchmove", function(e){
        $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you need to use space to separate events and not `,`. `.on("mousemove touchmove", function(){..`

Comment: Thanks, that always gets me! Fixed above.