# mousemove effect on mobile like on http://d3js.org/

Tags: mobile, jquery-ui-touch-punch

How could I transfer this 'scroll' effect from http://d3js.org/ to mobile devices (ipad, android,...)? 
It works on the desktop, but it won't work on mobile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get continuous mousemove event when using android mobile browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316503/how-to-get-continuous-mousemove-event-when-using-android-mobile-browser)

Comment: no, it doesnt work like that unfortunately. I've tried that.