# A workaround of the touchmove event bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I'm trying to execute some code whenever a `touchmove` event is fired. However, the `touchmove` event is very buggy right now. In many browsers, including the Android browser and Chrome 34.

[A "solution" does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316503/how-to-get-continuous-mousemove-event-when-using-android-mobile-browser) to try to "fix" this problem:

```
$('html').on('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

By adding `preventDefault` it will cause the browser to update the event. However it also stopped all further `touchmove` events which I didn't really want.

Is there, by any chance, a workaround that fixes this bug but also not cancelling the event? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need a bit more to it,  and I think the answer is somewhere in terms of using all the other events in coordination and managing an "active" state.

```
  el.on('touchstart mousedown', function(e) ...
  el.on('touchcancel', function(e)  ...
  el.on('touchmove mousemove', function(e)  ...
  el.on('touchend mouseup', function(e) ...
```

I use angular-touch for a few things and they seem to be tackling the same problems, its worth looking at some example code.
https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch/blob/master/angular-touch.js#L122