# Shouldn't touchmove trigger mousemove automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, touch-event, mousemove, touchmove

The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent) says:

> (...) even if a browser supports touch, the browser must still emulate
>   mouse events so content that assumes mouse-only input will work as is
>   without direct modification.

In my application, a `touchstart` event triggers the `mousedown` event. However, a `touchmove` event is not triggering the `mousemove` event (I just added an `alert` in the beginning of my `mouseMove` function, and it's never called).

The relevant lines of my code are:

```
<html onmousemove='mouseMove(event)' onmouseup='mouseUp(event)'>

<canvas onmousedown='cnvMouseDown(event)'></canvas>
```

The `mouseMove` and `mouseUp` functions are on the `html` element, so they'll work even if the cursor moves outside the canvas. Shouldn't this `mouseMove` be automatically caught by the `html`'s `touchmove` event? Why isn't it?

Comment: It depends on browser..Did you try it on different browser?

Comment: @Supercool. The only browser I have on my Android smartphone is Chrome.

Comment: ``even if a browser supports touch, the browser must still emulate mouse events so content that assumes mouse-only input will work as is without direct modification`` this is a specification that doesnt mean every browser will support it? thoughts?

Comment: Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316503/how-to-get-continuous-mousemove-event-when-using-android-mobile-browser

Comment: and also this https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/

Comment: @Supercool. "this is a specification that doesnt mean every browser will support it?" To me it's saying that in modern browsers (which support touch) it is mandatory to emulate "mouse events" (which should include mousemove). About the first link, it's several years old, uses jQuery, and only suggests to "use touchmove" instead. About the second link, "Supporting Mouse and Touch Together" #2 and #3 are interesting, but contradict the sentence I've copied from MDN. Is MDN simply wrong?

Answer (score 0):

MDI-***"even if a browser supports touch, the browser must still emulate mouse events so content that assumes mouse-only input will work as is without direct modification"***

It means if there is a browser that supports touch,it is must and recommended for that browser to emulate mouse events too so that if there are any scenarios which are associated with mouse events , those will work without having to explicitly handle them.

As of the `mousemove` and `touchmove`  ,they are not the same.

"***In particular, touch events always target the element where that touch STARTED, while mouse events target the element currently under the mouse cursor. This is why we have mouseover and mouseout events, but there are no corresponding touchover and touchout events - only touchend.***"

Hope this helps

Comment: So if I change my code to `<canvas onmousedown='cnvMouseDown(event)' onmousemove='mouseMove(event)' onmouseup='mouseUp(event)'></canvas>` should it work? Because I did it, and it still doesn't work. A single tap activates `mouseMove`, but sliding my finger over the canvas, doesn't.

Comment: So, is MDN lying about the specs, or doesn't Chrome follow them?

Comment: no its not like that. We cant mix mouse move with touch move .

Comment: MDN says we can, thus my question.